# How to add additional rows to an imported csv?

Tags: r, csv, row, irr

I am currently loading multiple csv-files into R in the following form:

```
read.csv("Cashflows2.csv", header = F, )
           V1      V2
1        Date Payments
2  18/08/2017  -20495*
3  18/04/2018  639.76*
4  18/05/2018  639.76
5  18/06/2018  639.76
6  18/07/2018  639.76
7  18/08/2018  639.76
8  18/09/2018  639.76
9  18/10/2018  639.76
10 18/11/2018  639.76*
11 18/05/2019  639.76*
12 18/06/2019  639.76
13 18/07/2019  639.76
14 18/08/2019  639.76
15 18/09/2019  639.76
16 18/10/2019  639.76
17 18/11/2019  639.76
18 18/12/2019  639.76
19 18/01/2020  639.76
20 18/02/2020  639.76
21 18/03/2020  639.76
22 18/04/2020  639.76
23 18/05/2020  639.76
24 18/06/2020  639.76
25 18/07/2020  639.76
26 18/08/2020  639.76
27 18/09/2020  639.76
28 18/10/2020  639.76
29 18/11/2020  639.76
30 18/12/2020  639.76
31 18/01/2021  639.76
32 18/02/2021  639.76
33 18/03/2021  639.76
34 18/04/2021  639.76
35 18/05/2021  639.76
36 18/06/2021  639.76
37 18/07/2021  734.76
```

However as denoted by the asterisk (which does not appear in the csv-file) there are a two periods in which no payments were made. Is there a function that would convert this csv-file into the following form in R:

```
read.csv("Cashflows2.csv", header = F, )
           V1      V2
1        Date Payment
2  18/08/2017  -20495
3  18/09/2017       0
4  18/10/2017       0
5  18/11/2017       0
6  18/12/2017       0
7  18/01/2018       0
8  18/02/2018       0
9  18/03/2018       0
10 18/04/2018  639.76
11 18/05/2018  639.76
12 18/06/2018  639.76
13 18/07/2018  639.76
14 18/08/2018  639.76
15 18/09/2018  639.76
16 18/10/2018  639.76
17 18/11/2018  639.76
18 18/12/2018       0
19 18/01/2019       0
20 18/02/2019       0
21 18/03/2019       0
22 18/04/2019       0
23 18/05/2019  639.76
24 18/06/2019  639.76
25 18/07/2019  639.76
26 18/08/2019  639.76
27 18/09/2019  639.76
28 18/10/2019  639.76
29 18/11/2019  639.76
30 18/12/2019  639.76
31 18/01/2020  639.76
32 18/02/2020  639.76
33 18/03/2020  639.76
34 18/04/2020  639.76
35 18/05/2020  639.76
36 18/06/2020  639.76
37 18/07/2020  639.76
38 18/08/2020  639.76
39 18/09/2020  639.76
40 18/10/2020  639.76
41 18/11/2020  639.76
42 18/12/2020  639.76
43 18/01/2021  639.76
44 18/02/2021  639.76
45 18/03/2021  639.76
46 18/04/2021  639.76
47 18/05/2021  639.76
48 18/06/2021  639.76
49 18/07/2021  734.76
```

Not all the csv-files have the same issue, so ideally the function would be applicable to multiple similar csv-files where not all of them experience periods with 0 payment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(37L, 22L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 18L, 
23L, 26L, 29L, 32L, 11L, 15L, 19L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 36L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
9L, 13L, 17L, 21L), .Label = c("18/01/2020", "18/01/2021", "18/02/2020", 
"18/02/2021", "18/03/2020", "18/03/2021", "18/04/2018", "18/04/2020", 
"18/04/2021", "18/05/2018", "18/05/2019", "18/05/2020", "18/05/2021", 
"18/06/2018", "18/06/2019", "18/06/2020", "18/06/2021", "18/07/2018", 
"18/07/2019", "18/07/2020", "18/07/2021", "18/08/2017", "18/08/2018", 
"18/08/2019", "18/08/2020", "18/09/2018", "18/09/2019", "18/09/2020", 
"18/10/2018", "18/10/2019", "18/10/2020", "18/11/2018", "18/11/2019", 
"18/11/2020", "18/12/2019", "18/12/2020", "Date"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("-20495", 
    "639.76", "734.76", "Payment"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-37L))
```

Comment: @Ringo Perhaps you're looking for something like this `df$Payment <- ifelse(grepl('\\*',df$Payment) == TRUE,'0',as.character(df$Payment))` I use a different version of a file, for you, instead of payment it would be V2

Comment: @Ronak Shah - for the example i put in the question i manually added the row's and changed the values to 0 in the original excel csv-file. I would like to find a function that does so automatically

Comment: @ Aaron Parilla I am getting the following error when using that code - `Error in df$Payment : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: @Ringo145 note that `df` is meant to be "your data" (whatever you've named it in your session). Apparently you didn't name your data `df` since the function `df` (see `?df`) is being used instead

Comment: No problem, the csv-file is being used to calculate the monthly IRR. Meaning that i require information for every month including those were no payments are made. Does that explanation help?

Comment: What you can do is change the first column to date objects, and check in the next entry is at one month difference. In the next entry is not one month later, add the missing months and put it to zero. Let me know if you see how to write this code, otherwise I can make an example, but then please give me you data in a reusable format, e.g. using `dput()`

Comment: @Chelmy88 that is exactly the kind of thing i would like to do! If you could produce an example that would be greatly appreciated. I have edited in `dput(df)` is that the kind of reusable data you need?

Comment: I think @kath answer does the job pretty well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `tidyr::complete` after reading the data with `header = TRUE`,  convert the `date` column into actual Date objects.

```
df <- read.csv("Cashflows2.csv", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "1 month"), 
          fill = list(Payments = 0))


# A tibble: 48 x 2
#   Date       Payments
#   <date>        <dbl>
# 1 2017-08-18  -20495 
# 2 2017-09-18       0 
# 3 2017-10-18       0 
# 4 2017-11-18       0 
# 5 2017-12-18       0 
# 6 2018-01-18       0 
# 7 2018-02-18       0 
# 8 2018-03-18       0 
# 9 2018-04-18     640.
#10 2018-05-18     640.
# … with 38 more rows
```

---

In base R, you could create a new dataframe with `max` and `min` of `Date`, `merge` them by `Date` and replace `NA`s with 0.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
compare_df <- data.frame(Date = seq(min(df$Date), max(df$Date), by = "1 month"))
df1 <- merge(compare_df, df, by = "Date", all.x = TRUE)
df1$Payments[is.na(df1$Payments)] <- 0
```

To apply this to multiple csv files, we can change this to a function and apply to list of dataframes using `lapply`

```
read_fun  <- function(df) {
   df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
   compare_df <- data.frame(Date = seq(min(df$Date), max(df$Date), by = "1 month"))
   df1 <- merge(compare_df, df, by = "Date", all.x = TRUE)
   df1$Payments[is.na(df1$Payments)] <- 0
   df1
 }

list_df <- lapply(list_df, read_fun)
```

Comment: This is great thanks! Ideally i would like to keep the solution in base R. I am getting the following error for the last line of code however -  `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Payments, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 48`

Comment: @Ringo145 Did you read data with `df <- read.csv("Cashflows2.csv", header = TRUE)` ? What does `dput(head(df1))` give to you ?

Comment: Yes i did. `dput(head(df1))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17396, 17427, 17457, 17488, 
17518, 17549), class = "Date"), Payment = c(-20495, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @Ringo145 I think there is a typo. You need to do `df1$Payment[is.na(df1$Payment)] <- 0`

Comment: Yes that's it thanks for the help! Could i use the `lapply` function to use this code on multiple csv-files?

Comment: @Ringo145 yes if you have list of dataframes and want to apply this to each one of them you can change this to . function and then use `lapply` to apply the function to each of the dataframe.  I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should read in the data using `header = TRUE` in `read.csv` as you have column names.

```
my_data <- read.csv("Cashflows2.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Then you can transform the Date column into a "proper" date column with

```
my_data$Date <- as.Date(my_data$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then, I think the an easy way to solve your task is the following. This however requires that you install the `tidyr`-package: (Use `install.packages("tidyr")`)

```
tidyr::complete(my_data, Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "month"), 
                fill = list(Payments = 0)) 

# A tibble: 48 x 2
#    Date       Payments
#    <date>        <dbl>
#  1 2017-08-18  -20495 
#  2 2017-09-18       0 
#  3 2017-10-18       0 
#  4 2017-11-18       0 
#  5 2017-12-18       0 
#  6 2018-01-18       0 
#  7 2018-02-18       0 
#  8 2018-03-18       0 
#  9 2018-04-18     640.
# 10 2018-05-18     640.
# ... with 38 more rows
```

This function takes your data, and expands the Date sequence, where we start at the minimum Date in your Data and go to the maximum Date, where the step size is one month. Further we want to fill the Payments column with zeros in the missing months.

You can save the updated data with

```
write.csv(my_data, "Cashflows2_updated.csv")
```

If you want to restore the previous Date-format you can use

```
my_data$Date <- format(my_data$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

before you save the file.

Comment: I see thankyou! I am getting N/A as apposed to 0. How do i know read.csv the expanded data sequence?

Comment: Maybe you need to specify `Payment = 0` (without s). Your example was ambiguous about the true header names in your csv - File. I do not understand the second question, do you mean `write.csv`?

Comment: Ah yes i shall try that now. I was just wandering i would call the updated csv-file back.